# How to find out what server an application is trying to connect to?

Tags: windows, networking

I have an application that is trying to connect to a remote server to retrieve a file. It errors out almost immediately. How can I find out what server it is trying to connect to?

Comment: Without knowing the application, we would have no idea where its config file would be. Some use the Registry, some use the program directory, some use the User profile, and at least one (badly behaved) program edited the executable for its configuration

Comment: I'm not sure the config file would contain the remote server address, I imagine it's compiled in the code. I've looked through the program directory and registry and there is no info related to a remote server.